# Bash encode array items to base64

Tags: arrays, bash, base64

I'm creating an array from a list of files in a directory.
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
file4.jpg
file5.jpg

I need to encode each of the items(file names) in the array to base64.  Then I need to make a comma separated list of them for use in an API request.

```
#!/bin/bash
array=($(ls /images/))
list=$(IFS=,; (echo "${array[@]}") | base64)
echo $list
```

Output:  `ZmlsZTEuanBnIGZpbGUyLmpwZyBmaWxlMy5qcGcgZmlsZTQuanBnIGZpbGU1LmpwZwo=`

The output of that is a space separated list of the file names all encoded base64 together, instead of individually and comma separated.

Wanted output:

```
ZmlsZTEuanBnCg==,ZmlsZTIuanBnCg==,ZmlsZTMuanBnCg==,ZmlsZTQuanBnCg==,ZmlsZTUuanBnCg==
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This is my first question and it matches the ask standards...doesn't it?

Comment: Personally, I think the question is fine. Don't be disheartened. By the way I just edited my answer to use a string rather than an array. Give it a go and see what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may as well just use a loop to do this:

```
list=""
for i in /images/*; do
    list+=",$(basename "$i" | base64)"
done
list=${list:1}
```

This loops through all of the images and builds a comma-separated list. There is a comma before the first value, which is removed at the end of the loop.

Comment: I've tried this on 2 systems (Linux and MacOS). It is returning a large chunk of base64 data, none of which is the file names of the directory specified. Am I missing something?

Comment: My mistake, I was encoding the files, not the filenames. It should do what you want now.

Comment: I have edited to use `basename`, which strips the directory from the filename.